# Error con el formato de fechas usando sequelize y angular

Tags: nodejs, angularjs

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en nodejs, angular y mysql. y me pasa que al guardar una fecha en la base de datos con el tipo date y recuperarla con el sequelize me lo regresa de la siguiente forma "1991-04-13T00:00:00.000Z" y al utilizarla en angular con el filtro date {{fecha | date }} me regresa 1991-04-12, he probado incluso con el moment js y me lo regresa de la mismo forma. hay alguna forma de corregir esto?

Comment: Disculpa por la pregunta algo tardía. Lograste resolver tu problema? Creo que tu uso horario es lo que esta afectando el resultado de tus fechas. Puedes decirme en que uso horario te encuentras y poner un ejemplo del código que usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar una función para convertir la fecha a tipo UTC, de la siguiente forma:

```
var fecha = new Date('1991-04-13T00:00:00.000Z'); 
var fecha_utc = new Date(fecha.getUTCFullYear(), fecha.getUTCMonth(), fecha.getUTCDate(),  fecha.getUTCHours(), fecha.getUTCMinutes(), fecha.getUTCSeconds());
```

En tu vista bastaría con llamarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 Fecha: {{fecha | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}!
</div>
```

Acá un ejemplo con JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfergt/ypua2v2q/

Comment: por cierto el parámetro después de la palabra "date" es el formato en que quiero la fecha, lo puedes quitar o ver la documentación acá:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

Si el tipo de dato que tienes puesto en tu base de datos es DATE y el Sequelize te esta devolviendo este tipo de formato "1991-04-13T00:00:00.000Z".

Estuve investigando en la documentacion de sequelize, y maneja formas de como devolver la fecha.

Si en tu modelo tienes definido como DATE sequelize te devuelve tipo datetime(Toma tu valor de fecha de mysql ej. 1991-04-13 y le da formato a tipo datetime).

Si solo vas utilizar fecha de tipo 1991-04-13 seria que cambies el tipo DATE de tu modelo a DATEONLY(Este solo te devuelve la fecha)

Te dejo el enlace:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#date

Espero que sea de utilidad